# BufferedReader drops lines

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-io

I'm writing to a `ServerSocket` like this in a separate thread from my main application:

```
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new Queue<>();

    // THREAD
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2222);
Socket socket = server.accept();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));

while (true) {
    String line = queue.take();

    if (line != null) {
        try {
            logger.debug("Sending command " + line);
            writer.write(line + "\n");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IO error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Where `queue` gets populated from the outside.

Sending stuff works fine, and I can verify this by using telnet on port 2222 and by reading the debug logger output.

On android I'm reading on port 2222 via the following code:

```
Socket s = new Socket("host",2222);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("PAINT","RECEIVED::" + line);

    // create Message, Bundle, send Message to handler.

}
```

However one in every few messages (like 1 in 10) I send does not get received by the android phone. Any hints on how this can happen and how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you aware that `Queue<T>` isn't thread-safe? You seem to be using it as if you expect it to be.

Comment: Good point, however it seems that while we should fix this it is not the issue; Every time the andoid thread doesn't register a read, I do log a write.

Comment: Use one of the collections in the `java.util.concurrent`. If you were to use a `BlockingQueue` like `LinkedBlockingQueue` then you could remove the horrible busy-wait antipattern you seem to be using.

Comment: Also note that you're using the default character encoding on each platform, which is never a good idea.

Comment: As a clue to debug, you could add a counter in every message you send so you get for sure what is missing.
For exmaple:
  counter++;
  writer.write(String.format("%3d: %s\n", counter, line));
  writer.flush();
with this you may know what is really being lost.

Comment: @ja_mesa That turned out to be a valuable hint, I'm on to the solution now: it turned out that the app launched more threads than it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, there were a number of issues with our code. It turned out that there were two threads writing to a buffer because the android app connected twice. Only one was writing to the correct socket. The absence of synchronisation on the queue made which thread was consuming events unpredictable, so it was hard to notice until after ja_mesa's hint of numbering the debug log.

It turned out that we had to terminate the outputwriter thread after the inputthread died.